# How to determine if an ELF file is a Go ELF file?

Tags: go, elf, readelf

I need to determine whether a given ELF file originated from Go. According to [this link](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/programming/GoBinaryStructureNotes):

```
$ readelf -a traefik.stripped | grep "\.note\.go\.buildid"
```

Is this in any way inferior to go's native way:

```
$ go tool buildid traefik.stripped
oPIWoPjqt1P3rttpA3ee/ByNXPhvgS37nIoJY-HYB/8b25JYXrgktA-FYgU5MU/0Posfq41xZW9BEPEG4Ub
```

Are both methods *guaranteed* to work on stripped binaries?

Comment: I'm sure it depends on what you mean by "guaranteed". No doubt it's possible to craft/modify an ELF binary that fools the tools, to either produce a false negative or a false positive.

Comment: @Flimzy can you describe a scenario where this section is removed *without* compromising the functionality of the ELF file?

Comment: I cannot. I'm not that familiar with ELF binary formats. But I know that this is exactly the sorts of things virus authors (and others) do, so I'm sure it can be done. Whether anyone would have a reason to do so, I don't know.  But you asked about guarantees. I don't think there are any.

Comment: Think of it this way: What's to prevent a Python script from building a byte-for-byte identical ELF binary, compared to one generated by a Go compiler? Nothing, obvoiusly, other than the time and motivation.

Comment: But if that is possible, then how come `strip` itself doesn't remove this section?

Comment: I don't know. That's a very different question. How/why strip behaves the way it does has little to nothing to do with the technical possibility of fooling a heuristic.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: can an innocent go developer build a golang ELF and accidentally remove this (redundant??) section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to determine whether a given ELF file originated from Go

That is *impossible* to do in general. What is and isn't a Go binary is not well defined, and a sufficiently optimized Go binary may end up containing just a few instructions. E.g. on `x86_64`, you may end up with a single `HLT` instruction.

> how come strip itself doesn't remove this section?

This section (indeed *every* section) is not necessary for execution -- you can remove *all* sections, and the binary will still work.

This section is present *only* to help developers identify a particular build.  `strip` doesn't remove it *by default* because that would defeat the purpose of this section, but it certainly *can* do so.

> can an innocent go developer build a golang ELF and accidentally remove this (redundant??) section

Sure. The developer can run a broken version of `strip`, or he can have aliased `strip` with `strip --strip-all`, or he could have used some other ELF post-processing tool, or he could have used UPX, or ...

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned section is a `NOTE` section:

```
$ readelf -a traefik.stripped | grep "\.note\.go\.buildid" | sed -n "1,1p"
  [11] .note.go.buildid  NOTE             0000000000400f9c  00000f9c
```

And apparently `NOTE` sections might sometimes be removed for size reductions ([related](https://lists.debian.org/debian-policy/1998/03/msg00256.html)):

```
objcopy --remove-section=.note.go.buildid traefik.stripped traefik.super.stripped
```

Removing the mentioned section does not seem to harm the integrity of the whole binary

Answer (score 1):

As for using standard go tools the section should be there, but there is a way that the go nature of a binary can be hidden without any malicious intent. Using [upx](https://upx.github.io/) to reduce the size of the binary will completely hide the go nature of the binary as upx works with binaries from any language.